# Que falla o cómo puedo hacer esto recursivamente en Haskell

Tags: recursión, haskell

Me piden hacer recursivamente que dados 3 listas de enteros, se concatene en la última lista la concatenación inversa de las dos primeras listas. Ejemplo:
invconc_aux [1,2,3] [4,5,6,7,8] [9,10] debería de quedar así [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,9,10]. Adjunto mi código:

```hs
invconc_aux :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
invconc_aux [] [] w = w
invconc_aux s r w
   | null s = invconc_aux s [head(tail r)] ++ ([head r] ++ w)
   | otherwise = invconc_aux [head(tail s)] r ([head s] ++ w)
```

Mi idea es que hasta que `s` no esté vacío se vayan concatenando los elementos de `s` al comienzo de `w`, y cuando `s` esté vacío se vayan concatenando los elementos de `r` al comienzo de `w`. Cuando `s` y `r` estén ambos vacíos se devolverá `w`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio, la idea está bien. En lugar de emplear las funciones `head` y `tail`, emplea los *patrones de llamada*, algo así:

```hs
invconc_aux :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
invconc_aux [] [] zs = zs
invconv_aux [] (y:ys) zs = invconv_aux [] ys (y:zs)
invconc_aux (x:xs) ys zs = invconv_aux xs ys (x:zs)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ChemaCortes!!!